# How to suppress warning due to a third-party PropTypes library in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got a plenty of warnings while using Stylesheet in React Native as following image.

[Warning on iOS simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnF5Q.png)

How to suppress it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to disable warnings for a specific component, but you can disable different types of warnings in your app. To disable all warnings, use:

```
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

To disable only certain warnings that start with a given string, specify an array of prefixes to filter out:

```
console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Warning: ...'];
```

For example, for the warning in the question you could write:

```
console.ignoredYellowBox = [
  'Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation',
];
```

Comment: @ide do i need to put this directly into my componenets like this   render() { console.disableYelowBox = true;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this._renderRow}
        />
      </View>
    );
  },

Comment: Put it somewhere that runs when your app boots up. Grep for disableYellowBox and look at the implementation for a better idea.

Comment: @WaleedArshad I put `console.ignoredYellowBox` above main component class's definition.

Comment: wow, this is making my propType checks utterley useless. Unfortunately React doesn't throw an exception when it fails against a propType check so I have to look around in the warnings. Unfortunately the warnings are being polluted by some third party. This is making my typechecking in react utterly utterly useless.

Comment: You should update your answer to the new YellowBox API. `console.ignoredYellowBox` does not work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

YellowBox API have changed from ReactNative 0.52:

To totally disable YellowBox: `console.disableYellowBox = true;`

To ignore some warnings:

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning text here...']);
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging#warnings

Answer (score 0):

In React v0.63 its been updated again.

```js
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning text here...']);
```

- [LogBox documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#logbox)