# React native don't Call PropTypes Warnings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

can anybody suggest how to remove third party warnings?
https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html

i don't know how to implement and where to put code that official documentation mentioned.
They take code from react-bootstrap

```
export default function deprecated(propType, explanation) {
   return function validate(props, propName, componentName) {
if (props[propName] != null) {
      const message = `"${propName}" property of 
         "${componentName}" has       been deprecated.\n${explanation}`;
  if (!warned[message]) {
    warning(false, message);
    warned[message] = true;
  }
}

return propType(props, propName, componentName);
};
}
```

Please write step by step to resolve third party warnings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is to prevent the "Yellow Box" debugging helper from appearing, you can use the `console.ignoredYellowBox` property to whitelist prefixes that should not be shown:

```
const existingIgnoreList = console.ignoredYellowBox;
const prefixesToIgnore = [
  'Warning: "foo" property of "Bar"'
];

console.ignoredYellowBox = existingIgnoreList
  ? existingIgnoreList.concat(prefixesToIgnore)
  : prefixesToIgnore;
```

*Edit based on comments*: If you want to actually suppress the console.error message entirely, there is no official and legitimate way to do this.

What you **can** do is monkey patch the `console.error` method and filter out that particular message. The patching needs to happen after your application code has been evaluated, but before the offending component is mounted.

A good place would be in your root component's `componentWillMount` handler:

```
componentWillMount() {
  console.__error = console.error;
  console.error = function overrideConsoleError(...args) {
    if (!typeof args[0] === 'string' || !args[0].startsWith('Warning: "foo" property of "Bar"')) {
      console.__error(...args);
    }
  };
}
```

But please, please don't actually do this. This is a really bad idea :)

Comment: yes there is a yellow box but official docs suggest something else. i am more willing to follow the recommendations that they mention in their official docs. anything you can suggest from the above code. The solution you provided already on the stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907803/how-to-suppress-warning-due-to-a-third-party-proptypes-library-in-react-native/38907884?noredirect=1#comment65901347_38907884

Comment: After implementing this solution, i am still having warning in red color in debugging console.

Comment: The problem is that the offending code isn't in your own codebase, it's in a third party module. The docs in your question are something the library author should do. In order for **you** to fix it you need to fork that library, patch the original cause of the problem, submit a pull request, wait for a new release etc. While you do that, if you need to remove the error, I've added a fun and creative way to get around the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code snippet where you are dealing with Proptypes? Maybe some library or even react native code is triggering these React warnings so check if your react native version matches the react right one.

Comment: These warnings are comming from thrid party library. i am not delaying with prototype