# Silence warning due to a third-party PropTypes library

Tags: reactjs, console, deprecation-warning

I'm getting the following warning due to a third-party package:

> Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.

As [the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html) recommends (*If it's not a library you wrote, you can file an issue against it*), there's already a PR done addressing the issue.

**In the meantime, is there anything I can do to suppress the warning?**

React native [apparantly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38907884/1417223) has a method called `console.ignoredYellowBox` to which you can define a string to hide in the console. Perhaps there's something similar for React (web)?

Comment: It's over one year and there is still not a single answer. We are doomed to see these warnings.